# Convert PKCS7 to PKCS12 using java.security.KeyStore

Tags: java, openssl, x509, pkcs#7

When I try to import a renewed X509 certificate on Chrome / Firefox (and probably other browser), it does not recognize that the certificate I am trying to import uses the same private key stored in my expiring user certificate with the same DN. I don't know if this is a bug with the implementation of certificate import tool of all major browsers, but I can (somewhat) work around this problem by storing my user certificate inside a private key-less PKCS12 file using openssl tool like following.

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in usercert.pem -nokeys -name "CN: Same Name" -out certonly.p12
>   (-nokeys is the trick here)

I don't know why this works, but I can then import certonly.p12 to Chrome / Firefox and it will attach my private key from the last year; although it creates a separate certificate entry so that I need to remove my old certificate manually.

So, I assume that, in order to renew my user certificate on my browser, I will need to package my certificate in PKCS12 format (with or without a pass-phrase).

Now, I need to do this in my Java application using java.security.KeyStore or similar libraries, because it is actually my web application which is generating user's renewed certificates. I don't want to ask our users to use the openssl command themselve to convert it to pkcs12 before importing to their browsers. My application should do this automatically, and provide them the renewed certificate contained inside a PKCS12 file.

I've looked many places, but so far I can't find a concrete example of how to do this using Java. Does anyone know how to output a pass-phrase less PKCS12 with only an issued certificate (or pkcs7) without a private key?

I tried something like following but it did not work.

```
java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain  = CertificateManager.parsePKCS7(renewed_cert_in_pkcs7);
KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
p12.load(null, null);
p12.setKeyEntry("USER Cert 123", null, "".toCharArray(), chain); 
response.setContentType("application/x-pkcs12");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=user_certificate_only.p12");
p12.store(response.getOutputStream(), "".toCharArray());
```